# React360 Entity example

Tags: virtual-reality, react-360

I am trying to use a 3d object in a react360 project. I followed the steps in [setup docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/setup.html). Created a project with `react-360 init Hello360` command and started the server with `npm start`.

Also, downloaded [this obj model](https://free3d.com/3d-model/stickman-with-fingers-29144.html), and put it into `static_assets` folder. Then, put an [Entity](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/entity.html) tag into `index.js` for displaying the object. Whole `index.js` is as follows.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Entity,
  asset
} from 'react-360';

export default class Hello360 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Entity source={{ obj: asset('stickman.obj') }} />
    );
  }
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Hello360', () => Hello360);
```

As a result, I can't see anything in the browser but the background image. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React360 docs Entity page](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/docs/entity.html) is missing the import part. Importing Entity as in [this blog](https://codeburst.io/react-360-by-example-part-4-c95f87c027f8) solves the problem.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  asset,
} from 'react-360';

import Entity from 'Entity';

...
```

Comment: Are you sure, docs are incorrect? Very strange. If yes, you should raise a concern with the community.

Comment: "Incorrect" was not the proper word for the situation. Actually, there is no code sample in that doc page for importing Entity. I edited my answer. I guess, [the community is aware of the problem](https://github.com/facebook/react-360/issues/501#issuecomment-392835045).